# N-back-for-matlab returned errors

Tags: matlab, nested-function

I downloaded nback from https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/67976-n-back-for-matlab

I am trying to set up this task in R2023b matlab, but there are numerous errors on the script for nback. For example, when I first try to run it I get the error message for line 116: Identifier 'nback' is not a function or a shared variable. To share 'nback' with a
nested function, initialize it in the current scope.

I am unsure what to do, and I've made sure that my path extended to my project folder which includes the function.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It seems like you should complain to the author, not us. We have nothing to do with that piece of code. The MATLAB File Exchange has a comment and a discussion section for each submission. That is the right place to complain about a submission not working. If you have a specific question about programming, feel free to come here to ask it. Follow the advice in [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Just need to uncomment lines 38, 39, and 42-61 per the discussion section of the file download site.